# Table not creating in SQL job

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a procedure it delete the data for a particular table . before deleting it will create a table and take the data as backup.
I have kept this procedure inside job ,will job running data is deleting but table not creating but manually running this SP it is working .

I'm the admin and I have full rights on that job but still I'm not able to create table inside job.

Comment: It's not easy to help you without code.

Comment: Please also explain how you're trying to execute this - through a direct `exec` of the stored procedure, or some other way.

Comment: What job history says? Any error message?

Comment: You may be an administrator, but the job probably isn't executing under your credentials. Is the job executing as `sa` and are you executing the stored procedure in the context of the database?